# Java Goose not extracting content on Android

Tags: java, android, scala, goose

I'm trying to set up a small Android application which extracts content from a web page using the Goose library. Since the library is written in Scala, I'm using the .jar I found [here](https://github.com/GravityLabs/goose/issues/59). The problem is, when I try to extract content from a page, it returns nothing. I successfully create an `Article` object using the URL I need, but the values of the object (title, domain, topImage etc.) are all `null`. I tried using different urls, to see if the problem was isolated to a single website, but it doesn't appear to be so.

The code I use to set up the `Goose` instance is this:

```
gooseDir = context.getCacheDir();
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.setLocalStoragePath(gooseDir.getAbsolutePath());
Goose goose = new Goose(config);
```

And then I just create the `Article` instance like so:

```
Article article = goose.extractContent(url);
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can't use the Goose library on Android due to incompatibilities, but you can use my Android version: https://github.com/milosmns/goose

It does almost the same thing as Goose, only works well on Android.